Why are Jn 7: .53 and Jn 8:1 in two separate Chapters?
John 8 appears to have an abrupt start:

but Jesus went to the Mount of Olives.

Apparently, Jn 8:1 takes over from the last verse of Jn 7 which reads :

And everyone went to his own house.

One wonders as to why Jn 7:53 and Jn 8:1 which otherwise seem to be part of one cohesive idea, were split and accommodated  in two separate Chapters. What is the explanation offered by Bible scholars ?

The choice of chapter endings and beginnings is arbitrary and has no bearing on the text. Chapters and verses were added long after the authors wrote the text. Wikipedia - Chapters and verses of the Bible.

One word answer - TRADITION - there is no good reason for the placement of most chapter divisions.

When the books of the Bible were originally written, there were no chapters or verses. Each book was written without any breaks from beginning to end.
The chapter and verse divisions were added to the Bible for the sake of convenience. There is no authoritative basis for the divisions we now find.
Thirteenth century:
A man named Stephen Langton divided the Bible into chapters in the year A.D. 1227. Langton was a professor at the University of Paris and later became the Archbishop of Canterbury.
Sixteenth century:
Robert Stephanus (Stephens), a French printer, divided the verses for his Greek New Testament. It was published in 1551.
The first entire Bible in which these chapter and verse divisions were used was Stephen’s edition of the Latin Vulgate (1555). The first English New Testament to have both chapter and verse divisions was the Geneva Bible (1560). Jewish scholars have also followed the way of dividing the Hebrew Scripture into chapters and verses.
Human-made divisions:
It must always be remembered that the divisions into chapters and verses are human-made. They are sometimes arbitrary and can interfere with the sense of the passage. The first step in Bible interpretation is to ignore the modern chapter and verse divisions.




Reference:





Bible, B. L. (2012, April 17). Why Is the Bible Divided into Chapters and Verses? https://blogs.blueletterbible.org/blb/2012/04/17/why-is-the-bible-divided-into-chapters-and-verses/




Excellent information. Up-voted +1.

I believe that the clue lies with Verses 2 onwards of Chapter 8:
> At dawn he appeared again in the temple courts, where all the people gathered around him, and he sat down to teach them . These who arranged the texts of Pre- arrangement Chapters 7 and 8 may have thought it good open Chapter 8 with the statement that Jesus prayed through the night on the mount before coming down at dawn to teach. They also may have wanted to Open Ch. 8 with the  story of how Jesus saved the woman from certain death.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Though they are human-made, I believe it would make sense that the chapter and verse divisions were occasionally placed to improve the narrative flow and highlight important moments in Jesus' life and teachings. So, although I don't know for sure, your idea would make sense.

Thanks,Jason_ for the moral support.

I have not heard an explanation from "Bible scholars" but you can start much further back and ask why all of the books are not compiled chronologically in the first place; especially since there are so many precise dates and nearly everything is mentioned twice as to satisfy the test of two or three witnesses.
The chapters of Daniel are similarly disorganized so take note of the year each ruler when studying Daniel.
Compare Jeremiah 33:14-26 in the LXX to a modern KJV. Jeremiah 33:14-26 is not recorded in the LXX because "Some think the promises are too exaggerated in their predictions since none of them have happened so far, but the time when this will happen is in the days to come, meaning the distant future."
But wait, there's more: The KJV Apocrypha AV which includes 14 books which add a great deal of context for what's happening all throughout the "New Testament" was printed as one book with the last version being the 1611 KJV. Printing it stopped once it began to be printed in the United States to "save on printing costs" as one statement has issued.
There is one common thread with each instance mentioned.
Two things I believe are true, when a story flows seamlessly from point to point, understanding can increase. When it doesn't, misunderstanding is bound to happen. Praise YAH for the Ruach ha Kodesh!
Conclusion: If if were an isolated instance, I would count it as an oddity. However, in light of the few observations i've mentioned, I don't think any of it is really accidental after 2000 years of people pouring over the text.
